# Adding a point to an OSMnx plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, osmnx

I'm trying to add a point to an existing OSMnx plot in a Jupyter notebook like so

```
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = ox.graph_from_address('1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500', 
                          distance=500)

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)

ax.scatter(-77.036498, 38.897270, c='red')

plt.show()
```

but my point(-77.036498, 38.897270) is not showing up.  Any ideas?

```
print (type(fig), type(ax))
<class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'> <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is `ox.plot_graph` will show your graph before you plot your point. And please note that if you set `show=False`, `ox.plot_graph` will close the figure by default. You will need to change your `ox.plot_graph` to:

```
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, show=False, close=False)
```

Hopefully the following graph is what you want:

[image]